Question on spatiotemporal dimensionality about the contradictions of time being a dimension
We can axiomatically see that all spatial dimensions have a fundamental rule where they can either move back or forwards infinitely. However, the temporal dimension started when the universe began and can only move forwards as time traveling backwards breaks the laws of physics. How can time be a dimension if it contradicts the very meaning of a dimension? I have heard interpretations about time being an aspect of a physical rate of change, and I agree with that more as it's a more likely interpretation.

Time is not like a spatial dimension. Time is that which the clocks show. A clock is a system that consists of a local energy reservoir that disperses this energy in a well defined way towards infinity. In an empty universe this energy will flow at the speed of light, which sets an upper limit for the speed of causality. So what we are looking at is not a dimension in which we can move like in space but at a geometric constraint on causality.

time traveling backwards breaks the laws of physics note that most laws on the microscopic scale (e.g. the standard model) are time-reversal invariant.

Nothing moves or "travels" in spacetime. 4D Spacetime is a mathematical model of how things move in 3D space. Imagine a satellite orbiting a planet in space. In spacetime, the planet is a long tube, running all the way though spacetime, parallel to the time axis; and the satellite is a corkscrew, wrapped around that tube. The corkscrew doesn't move. But, if you take "slices" of the spacetime, making the cuts perpendicular the time axis, you get a movie of the satellite's motion around the planet.

See Solomon's answer - in spacetime, there is no "travelling", just static curves that represent where a particle was/is/will be. The direction of time is actually arbitrary, so long as it is consistent; most physics is invariant under time-reversal (hence, CPT symmetry).

There's a lot of misconceptions here. I will try to clear them all up one by one, but first we should review what a dimension is in the mathematical context of analytic geometry. A dimension in this context is a number needed to specify a point in a space. The number of dimensions a space has is how many numbers you need to specify a point. To fully specify a point in the universe, we need to specify not only where we are, but also when. It is in this sense that time is a "dimension".

We can axiomatically see that all spatial dimensions have a fundamental rule where they can either move back or forwards infinitely.

This is not a mathematical axiom, and even if it were, nature is under no obligation to obey human mathematics. That we can use mathematics to model physics to such striking accuracy is nothing short of a miracle sometimes.

However, the temporal dimension started when the universe began and can only move forwards as time traveling backwards breaks the laws of physics.

The spatial dimensions also "began" at the Big Bang. It was the beginning of the entire universe, that is, 4D spacetime. As was noted in the comments above, quantum systems sometimes are time-reversal invariant, so that "going back in time" is indeed in accordance with physical laws.

I have heard interpretations about time being an aspect of a physical rate of change [...]

For classical physics, this is a perfectly valid way to look at it. Interpretations like this become somewhat cumbersome when time itself becomes subject to change, such as due to gravitational time dilation. In such cases one uses an arbitrary parameter along an observer's path through the universe to model change. Sometimes, this parameter can be the time read off a clock in the observer's rest frame, but not always.
P.S. I did not go into details about the specific geometry of Lorentzian spaces such as Minkowski space or the spacetime manifold on purpose. These all presuppose a 3+1 dimensional framework, whereas the question is about why the +1 is there in the first place.

Quantum systems can't go backwards in time because energy doesn't flow from infinity backwards into the energy reservoir of the clocks. For a clock to go backwards the energy flow in the entire local universe of the clock would have to reverse, which would cause a break in causality at the border of such a local time-reversal bubble. The reason why energy can only flow one way is also geometry: there is always more "over there" than there is "right here". The only universe in which "there" and "here" have equal volume is a one dimensional universe. Does such a universe have an arrow of time?
